# Check if all values of a list are less than a certain number, if not set it to that number

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python and I want to make sure that all values in the list are greater than some value. If not then I want to set it to that value.

eg: let us assume the list is

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

and the value to compare is 3. So I want the list to become

```
a = [3,3,3,4]
```

I can do this by iterating through all the elements in the list. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: That sounds easy. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Tichodromamuraria I did this through a loop, but want to know what is the best way to do it, without using a loop.

Comment: @Sundar Since you have to go through each and every element in the list, you must traverse over the entire list which boils down to running a loop.

I was wondering if you could check the condition,
is item being appended < min while you create your list. Then you could create your final list without traversing the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reconstruct the list with a simple conditional expression and list comprehension, like this

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print [item if item > 3 else 3 for item in a]
# [3, 3, 3, 4]
```

For every `item` in `a`, it checks if it is greater than `3`, then use `item` as it is otherwise use `3`.

This is similar but very efficient than the following,

```
result = []
for item in a:
    if item > 3:
        result.append(item)
    else:
        result.append(3)
```

But remember that list comprehension creates a new list. So, you have may have to do

```
a = [item if item > 3 else 3 for item in a]
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I have to wait another 10 minutes to accept your answer though :) From a performance perspective both create new lists right? So how is the first solution better from performance perspective?

Comment: @Sudar Every time `append` method in `result` has to resolved at runtime. Though we can assign that to a variable like `append_method = result.append` and use it like `append_method(item)`, the byte code generated for List comprehension is very optimized than the normal iterated version.